# Why do you have to reload a webpage to display $_COOKIES but not for $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

Say that I have created cookies with a submit button, why do I have to reload the page in order to see cookies in my console meanwhile if I created session instead it shows immediately in my console without needing to refresh the page? (Yes I know I don't have anything to remove cookies, not relevant to the question.)

```
<php
function createCookie($indata) {
$_setcookie('data', $_POST['hidLang'], time () + 60 + 5));
}

$output= <p>I have the cookie: " $_COOKIE["data"]<p/>
?>

<html>
...
<?php
echo($output)>

<form action=<?php echo ( $_SERVER[PHP_SELF"] ); method="post">
<input type=hidden name="hidLang" value="PHP" />
<input type=submit name=btnCreate class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
</form>
....
</html>
```

Comment: `$_COOKIE` comes from client `$_SESSION` is on the server. You could do `setcookie(` and `$_COOKIE..=`

Comment: Thank you for the reply but doesn't answer my question unfortunantly, I am aware that cookie is on client and session is on the server.

Comment: Can you please add code in that case to show what you are doing?

Comment: I have added in the code for you to take a look at, but please take in mind that I don't need help with the code, only the theoretical question of why cookies need to be reloaded to show on webpage while sessions do not.

Comment: `$_setcookie` is calling https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php? `$_COOKIE["data"]` is not set when PHP loads, you send it to the browser after this load. Loads after this load would have it. If you have `$_COOKIE["data"] = ` in `$_setcookie()` definition please add that code... This code also is open to XSS injections.

Comment: So if I had it like $_setcookie($_COOKIE['data'], $_POST['hidLang'], time () + 60 + 5)); it would be showing directly on the webpage? Without the need to load the page? or does it still need to load for it to be shown?

Comment: You need to run the native PHP function `_setcookie()` to set the cookie on the browser. `$_COOKIE["data"] =` would set it for the current PHP execution, when you have just sent it back to the browser but PHP didn't get it on the initial load.

Comment: I see, I think I have gotten more clearity as to why it doesn't show on initial load, because it has insufficient data inside the setcookie() function. Thank you for helping me out.